# PHP7: Unknown hashing algorithm: sha256

Tags: php-7

In PHP7, when I hash a string like this:

```
$hash = hash("sha256", "password");
```

I have this warning:

```
Unknown hashing algorithm: sha256
```

In PHP 5.2.9, it was working. Is the sha256 deprecated in php7? Other idea?

Notes

- the extension "php_openssl.dll" is enabled.
- hash("sha512", "password");  // WORKS !
- `print_r( hash_algos() );`

  `[0] => md2 [1] => md4 [2] => md5 [3] => sha1 [4] => sha224 [5] => sha256 
  [6] => sha384 [7] => sha512 ...`

Comment: Instead try `"sha2"`.

Comment: That's odd, it probably should work: https://3v4l.org/ICYr5

Comment: That said, you probably shouldn't hash passwords with SHA256. Use password_hash.

Comment: Check the array you get back from `hash_algos` and see if it is there.

Comment: sha2 does'nt work. sha512 works. Andrea, thanks for the tip (password_hash), but I can't use it now.

Comment: I added print_r( hash_algos() ); and then after somes calls to the php script,   hash("sha256", ...) works.. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you got it to work, but I wanted to add that I've looked through the PHP7 source code and there's simply no reason why it shouldn't work every time.

In [`./ext/hash/hash.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71c19800258ee3a9548af9a5e64ab0a62d1b1d8e/ext/hash/hash.c), we define our table of available hashes:

```c
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(hash)
{
    // ...
    zend_hash_init(&php_hash_hashtable, 35, NULL, NULL, 1);

    // ...
    php_hash_register_algo("sha224",        &php_hash_sha224_ops);
    php_hash_register_algo("sha256",        &php_hash_sha256_ops);
    php_hash_register_algo("sha384",        &php_hash_sha384_ops);
    php_hash_register_algo("sha512",        &php_hash_sha512_ops);
    // ...
}
```

`php_hash_register_algo()` is also very simple:

```c
PHP_HASH_API void php_hash_register_algo(const char *algo, const php_hash_ops *ops) /* {{{ */
{
    size_t algo_len = strlen(algo);
    char *lower = zend_str_tolower_dup(algo, algo_len);
    zend_hash_str_add_ptr(&php_hash_hashtable, lower, algo_len, (void *) ops);
    efree(lower);
}
```

So what of `php_hash_sha256_ops`? That's defined in [`./ext/hash/hash_sha.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71c19800258ee3a9548af9a5e64ab0a62d1b1d8e/ext/hash/hash_sha.c):

```c
const php_hash_ops php_hash_sha256_ops = {
    (php_hash_init_func_t) PHP_SHA256Init,
    (php_hash_update_func_t) PHP_SHA256Update,
    (php_hash_final_func_t) PHP_SHA256Final,
    (php_hash_copy_func_t) php_hash_copy,
    32,
    64,
    sizeof(PHP_SHA256_CTX)
};
```

By looking at the code in this file, you can also see that there are no preventative conditions in `PHP_SHA256Init()`, `PHP_SHA256Update()`, or `PHP_SHA256Final()`. I can't find a single possible way that `sha256` could be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

What it boiled down to for me was that due to a forgotten comment in configs I was using mod_php with mpm_event apache. So non-thread-safe php7 in a threaded environment, hence shared memory corruption and a number of problems, one of them being sha1 was unavailable after some random uptime.

Answer (score 1):

1)Open localhost/phpmyadmin or 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin which certainly gives you an error.

2).To fix this, restart the server to start the service of PHPMYADMIN.

3).if you are on local server, open your xampp or wampp, stop all services then start it.

4).This will fix your all issues for sure

Comment: [reason for downvote] phpmyadmin has nothing to do with the question. It's about hashing, not database management.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. It resolved itself after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

just needed to Restart xampp or MAMP to fix the issue.